# improving speed on strings with math operators in python

Tags: python

I am working with a set of strings that could contain math operators, either '+' or '-' for now. Initially i used eval which was pretty straightforward. I am trying to move away from eval due to its known issues but mostly am trying to improve the speed. Here is a typical set of string that i would work on :

```
DAC = ('12','0x1E','34','12+20','2+0x1F')
```

Taking each value and applying the eval will give the results i need. To move away from this I tried a few methods, they work fine until i hit into a math operator. I did read about AST module and am gonna work on that but would like to get some feedback if its the right track to go in terms of improving the speed or any other suggestions the community can give me..

Thanks

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26130511/2867928

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with `literal_eval`? That's probably your best bet short of writing or finding a lex parser, which is certainly overkill for this situation.

```
>>> DAC = ('12','0x1E','34','12+20','2+0x1F')
>>> from ast import literal_eval
```

You could use a list comprehension

```
>>> [literal_eval(i) for i in DAC]
[12, 30, 34, 32, 33]
```

Or `map`

```
>>> list(map(literal_eval, DAC))
[12, 30, 34, 32, 33]
```

Comment: Unfortunately `literal_eval('12+20')` is not going to work in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

As I measured, in Python 3 where it's able to use operators, `ast.literal_eval` is a bit **slower** than plain `eval`.  So the fastest approach might be:

```
def myeval(s):
    try: return int(s, 0)
    except ValueError: return eval(s)
```

Having placed this and your definition of `DAC` in x.py, I then measure:

```
aleax-macbookair4:~ aleax$ python3 -mtimeit -s'import x' '[eval(a) for a in x.DAC]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 usec per loop
aleax-macbookair4:~ aleax$ python3 -mtimeit -s'import x' '[x.myeval(a) for a in x.DAC]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.9 usec per loop
```

so, a modest speedup.

Actually, for once, a "LBYL" approach may be a little bit better than the usually preferable "EAFP" one: adding to x.py the following

```
def alteval(s):
    if '+' in s or '-' in s: return eval(s)
    else: return int(s, 0)
```

I then measure:

```
aleax-macbookair4:~ aleax$ python3 -mtimeit -s'import x' '[x.alteval(a) for a in x.DAC]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.1 usec per loop
```

for another, though smaller, increase in performance.  (I've also tried using `re` to find out if `s` has a plus or minus, but that appears to be slower).

Comment: Thks Alex, so basically i only use eval for those with math opertors and that should get me the increase in performance

Comment: Right, that the core idea.  In Python 3, using `ast.literal_eval` is safer, but it can cost you a modicum of performance.